# Squash4Jenkins - Documentation

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, squash

I have come to know there is now a new plugin available to trigger a build and get the results in Squash TM. Can someone please tell me if there is any available documentation on how to implement this plugin? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has just been released on Jenkins marketplace.
You can find the documentation on [this page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Squash4Jenkins+Plugin).

Regards,
Marion